# lost resque jobs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

While I restart resque workers during deploy if new job comes in, then these jobs are set as queued in resque-status but it's not actually queued in resque. So my jobs are lost.

[image: queued]

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :027 > status=Resque::Status.get("f050dd20bc45012e1e77723c9193eb99")
 => #<Resque::Status {"time"=>1315485749, "status"=>"queued", "uuid"=>"f050dd20bc45012e1e77723c9193eb99"}>

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :022 > status.status
 => "queued"

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :033 > Resque.info
 => {:pending=>0, :processed=>12943, :queues=>9, :workers=>10, :working=>0, :failed=>8911, :servers=>["redis://192.168.###.###:6379/0"], :environment=>"production"}
```

As you can see there are 12 jobs with queued status but they're not showing up in Queues tab as there is no job pending in resque.

How can I fix this [issue](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/issues/42)?

Is there any method to requeue these workers??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in 0.3.3 https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/commit/dde6dcadcc248561aa223b6085b40d1c6e6a621b